# Where to download or install cent os 32 bit

Tags: iso

i m unable to find 32 bit iso for CentOs.
I tried on google it is giving me 64 bit only and in my virtual box 64 option is missing.

Comment: CentOS 7 doesn't have one yet. try CentOS 6, if you must: http://isoredirect.centos.org/centos/6/isos/i386/

Answer (score 1):

CentOS 7 is available only for x86_64. You can try 6 instead. [download_link](http://wiki.centos.org/Download)